# Formulario de Login donde el usuario tenga solo tres oportunidades para ingresar la contraseña

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy realizando un *login* en HTML y Javascrip donde si el usuario no acierta correctamente la contraseña (que es *158974*) le aparece la primera alerta de

> Intente de nuevo

... pero si el usuario acierta  muestra la alerta de

> Contraseña correcta

El problema es que no sé cómo aguardar la contraseña que el usuario ingresa.

```
<form>
    <h2>Formulario de Login</h2>
    <label >Ingrese Contraseña:</label>
    <input type="password" placeholder="&#9919; Contraseña" name="tagName"  >
    <input type="button" value="Enviar" onclick="enviarFormulario()">
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function enviarFormulario() {
        var contrase=158974;
        var veces=0; 

        //Do while
        do {
            var elements = element.getElementsByTagName("tagName").value;
            //capturando la variable password
            if(elements == contrase) {
                alert('Contraseña Correcta');
                veces=3;//indicando la salida si acierta la contraseña
            } else {
                alert('Contraseña Iconrrecta Intente de nuevo');
                veces = veces + 1;//incremento el numero de intentos
                if(veces == 3) {
                    alert('Acceso restringido');
                    alert('Saliendo de la pagina .....');
                }
            }
        } while(veces < 3);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Ya estas guardando la contraseña, mas bien donde quieres guardarla??, o en que sentido quieres guardarla??, porque asi como tienes el codigo ya tienes una contraseña guardada. Aunque por supuesto, es una contraseña guardada temporalmente (desaparecera cuando cierres la ventana), que es lo que deseas??, guardarla en una sesion (login del usuario session storage), guardarla en un servidor (base de datos memoria extendida) o guardarla en el navegador (local storage) para que pueda ser consultada hasta que el usuario decida borrar los datos de navegacion??

Answer (score 1):

La deberias guardar en el backend.

De forma provisional e informal
la puedes guardar en el "LocalStorage" 
ej.
localStorage.setItem(Date.now(), passw );

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola fede, se considera que si la pregunta puede ser respondida sin el uso de imágenes mucho mejor, o si aquello que describía la imagen puede ser escrito en código, que lo coloques como código, las imagenes son mas bien para ilustrar algun concepto, considera editar la respuesta y formatearla como codigo (lo que sea codigo).